# What is a correct way to express this?

Tags: sentence-choice

How do I express a person who is both shock and hurt from breakup confession? What is a correct way to say it? *‘his face filled with a mixture of shock and hurt.‘*

I feel it is bit weird to write it that way so what is better way to write it?

Answer (score 1):

> ‘his face filled with a mixture of shock and hurt.‘

There is a question of what style you prefer to convey. Each alternative has different nuances.

A few possible choices:

> - his expression filled with a mixture of shock and hurt.
> - his countenance filled with a mixture of shock and pain.
> - his expression filled with a mixture of shock and anguish/distress.

Answer (score 0):

You could reframe it like this -

> His face was reflecting an amalgamation of shock and hurt.
>
> He was not only shocked, but also hurt.
>
> His face could not tell if he was more shocked than hurt.

The original sentence doesn't look natural. A reader might surely stumble upon the sentence and think that it is not very well framed. It's best to consider any of the above.

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to address OP’s version and explain why you chose your examples?

Comment: Done. I have edited the post. Please check it